# Close a looping javax.sound.sampled clip

Tags: java, javasound

I'm probably approaching this incorrectly but I need to find out how to stop a looping javax.sound.sampled clip. I have 9 different sounds. I want a different sound to play as a user presses an increase amplitude button. At the moment I'm calling the playSound method each time they click the button and it's working, however it's not stopping sounds that are already playing. The sounds just play over each other.

Is there a way to close all existing sounds when the user presses the button?

Here's my playSound code:

```
    public void playSound(){
    try {
        audio = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile[activeSound]);
        clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(audio);
        clip.start();
        clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);           
    }

    catch (IOException ex){
        System.out.println("Sorry but there has been a problem reading your file.");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException ex1){
        System.out.println("Sorry but the audio file format you are using is not supported.");
        ex1.printStackTrace();
    }

    catch (LineUnavailableException ex2){
        System.out.println("Sorry but there are audio line problems.");
        ex2.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

I've been at this for two days now and it's driving me mad. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Nice exception handling. +1  Also, welcome to SO.  :)

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to stop all existing clips from playing. That can be done using the [Dataline.stop()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/DataLine.html#stop%28%29) method. All you need is to be able to access all existing clips. Below is my suggestion. Note that I only use one reference to link to the currently looping clip. If you have more than one, use `ArrayList<Clip>` instead of only one.

```
private Clip activeClip;
public void playSound(){
    activeClip.stop();
    try {
        audio = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile[activeSound]);
        clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(audio);
        clip.start();
        clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
        activeClip = clip;
    }

    catch (IOException ex){
        System.out.println("Sorry but there has been a problem reading your file.");
        ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException ex1){
        System.out.println("Sorry but the audio file format you are using is not     supported.");
        ex1.printStackTrace();
    }

    catch (LineUnavailableException ex2){
        System.out.println("Sorry but there are audio line problems.");
        ex2.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

Comment: +1 but one minor suggestion.  Going your route, the `clip` attribute could be declared locally to the method.

Comment: Could it? I was under the impression that the lifespan of a variable is limited to the time it takes for the method to finish execution.

Comment: Thanks for your reply lads but NetBeans is giving an error at the activeClip.stop(); line. I presume it's because the first time the method gets called, there is no clip playing?

Comment: Solved. I had to add the following code: if (clip != null && clip.isRunning()) {
 clip.stop();
}  Thanks again for your help.